# How to protect yourself against SQL Injection in dynamic queries?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-injection

My application gets in a String object query to the database. E.g. `String query = EMAIL like '% test%' and USER_NAME like '% user%'`. The query is built dynamically and I do not know its structure, so I can not take advantage of `PrepareStatement`. Does anyone know of a way that in this case to guard against SQL injection?

Database: Oracle
Language: Java 1.6

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

Even if you do not know the structure, you can use a `PreparedStatement`. Let me demonstrate with a simple example:

```
List<Object> arguments = new ArrayList<Object>();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE someCondition = ?";
if (queryOnEmail) {
  sql = sql + " AND email LIKE ?";
  arguments.add(email);
}
if (queryOnUserName) {
  sql = sql + " AND user_name LIKE ?";
  arguments.add(userName);
}
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
int i = 1;
for(Object o : arguments) {
  stmt.setObject(i, o);
  i++;
}
```

Of course you can wrap this SQL + arguments construct into its own class to simplify its usage.

Comment: No, no.  I can not do just as you showed. I do not know how explicit query string looks like. It may look like the example I gave in, and may be more complicated example (EMAIL like% a% AND FIRST_NAME like "% usr% ') AND (Somthing operator somethin) OR ....

Comment: Yes, I understood that: you will **have to** change the way that query string is constructed, or you won't be able to avoid SQL injection attacks. **If** the string is exactly as you've shown, then the SQL injection has already happened and you can't reliably "fix" it before executing the SQL.

Comment: @user612925, no matter how special your queries are, you can still use PreparedStatements. You have to start by recognizing the structure of the queries built, and associate bind parameters accordingly. In simpler words, you'll need to know what are these arguments, their types and their order.

Comment: hmm, can you give me an example?

Comment: @Vineet: if the query already contains the argument in-line, then such a task boils down to implementing the same thing as the database does. And it will have the exact same problems: there's **no way** to distinguish a maliciously injected query parameter from a valid one!

Comment: Just a little tip: When you want to build your SQL dynamically then it often helps when you start where clause with `1=1`. This helps because you do not havbe to care then if it's the first condition (that must not have `AND`) or a later condition (that must have `AND`). i.e. use this as base SQL: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1=1` and dynamically add every needed condition with `AND`.

This helps to avoid MUCH boilerplate code just for checking if you need an `AND` or not.

Comment: @user612925, you'll need a class (a bean) that stores the column name (which you should know before hand) and the value to be bound; if necessary store other information like the operators used to compare the column and the bound value (which you should know as well). Put instances of these beans in collection. Iterate through the collection, using the column names and operators to construct the query, and bind each column with the value (using PreparedStatements).

Comment: @Joachim, yes, I figured that part out. His design is messed up. I've proposed one that requires him to know upfront what is safe, so that he can construct safe queries, and bind unsafe values using PreparedStatements.

Comment: And if I was able to specify the attributes of a table that can be used to build a query? Terms example: {EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, USER_ID, PHONE}

And I thought that only those terms in the query can be String? I could then protect themselves?

Comment: @user612925: not really: a maliciously injected argument could modify your query to still only query those fields but in a way that you did not expect (for example it could add `"OR EMAIL IS NOT NULL"`).

Comment: @user612925, I suppose it would be clear, after Joachim's previous comment, as to why you need to separate the safe and unsafe bits of your query. The bean's design proposed earlier, does exactly that - it doesn't allow unsafe values into the column name and the operator by letting a programmer specify it (after sanity checks), leaving any unsafe input for escaping by a PreparedStatement.

Comment: @user612925, I suspect that you are creating the query at the client, or in a class where you are not using PreparedStatements. If that is the case, change that design to use PreparedStatements.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically build list of variables for statement when you build query and use PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this post](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-injection-and-how-you-should-prevent-it/), there are more bad things that can happen to your application than the classic table `DROP`:

- call a sleep function so that all your database connections will be busy, therefore making your application unavailable
- extracting sensitive data from the DB
- [bypassing the user authentication](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Bottom line, you should never use string concatenation when building SQL statements. Use a dedicated API for that purpose:

- [JPA Criteria API](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-always-check-criteria-api-sql-queries/)
- [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)

Answer (score -6):

In addition: it is ALWAYS good practice to NEVER trust a users input. Before you process any input data first remove all escape and special characters:
`String.replace("\\" | "\"", "");`

Comment: It's very easy to miss some attack vector this way. It's safer to let that work be done by the JDBC driver itself.

Comment: -1. Doesn't help against JOINs and sub-queries. Extremely useless against function call injection in Oracle.

Comment: No, it would give an indication of what measures you are using to protect. With that, a more targetted attack can be framed. If you want to handle special characters, removing them is a bad idea. It's better to throw an exception or return an error.

Comment: I agree that my method should not be your only line of defense, but scanning for malformed input from user can't be that bad of an idea...

Comment: -1 for recommendation something will fail. When not today then tommorrow. Please never try to prevent SQL Injections that way ...
Addiotional checking may not hurt, but is redundant when using Prepared Statements the right way.

Comment: @BadSkillz: you're right: additional lines of defense hardly ever hurt. **But** suggesting this as a solution makes it highly possible that it will end up as the **only** line of defense, for which it is definitely lacking.

Comment: -1 for mangling user input.  If you're doing things right, data should make it in and out of the DB without restrictions like "the character `"` is not allowed".  The only time you should ever be altering the data, disallowing certain chars, etc is if there is a valid *business* reason why.  "I can't be bothered to use prepared statements or quote my data properly" is no excuse.